# how to create hibernate 5 project with assembly plugin

Tags: java, hibernate

I have hibernate project and i want to read some configuration files from out of jar file. i am doing it with assembly plugin and with hibernate 3.6.3.Final and it is working fine.
here is my assembly plugin

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>ge.ufc.br.ud.generator.App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>./conf/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but when I am going to change hibernate version to 5 this plugin is not working( can not see /conf folder and configuration files in this folder) how can I read them in hibernate 5 ?

Comment: Like this one? https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: like this but i need <manifestEntries> to put my folder (jar-file-path/conf) in classpath